# Find not-accepted answer

Tags: support

I had answers on a question that got unaccepted, but I can't find the parent question url from statistics shown on my profile page (not listed). How can I find them so?

Answer (score 1):

You can see your removed answer *if it had upvotes* when you enable *show removed posts* in the reputation tab on your profile:

[image: screenshot]

A moderator can see all your deleted posts, and in your case there was just one on [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18652/get-category-id-inside-category-template).

The complete text of that answer is:

> ```
> global $wp_query;
> $cat_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id;
> ```
>
> ***Update:*** More clear answer

It was not an accepted answer (the asker didn't show up on our site since 2011), and it had no upvotes.

This is the same as the the answer from Jan Fabry, there is no explanation and no visible update. So I have deleted it and added an explanation for you in a comment.

Note that bare code fragments are rarely good answers. If you think your answer just *looks* like another answer but is really something different, you have to explain that, so other readers can understand it.

Comment: with that option, again I can't see it. It's for questions not answers

Comment: Only posts _with upvotes_ are visible with that option.

Comment: why a post with *upvotes* should be removed?

Comment: That's a different question. Your post had no upvotes, and it was not accepted, that's why you cannot see it.

Comment: u say a removed post with upvotes! I confused here. an upvoted post has positive side, i think `a removed post with downvotes` should be correct?

Comment: @revo See my update, I hope it is more clear now.